# gui2py with Phoenix (wxPython) Visual Tools error

Tags: python-3.x

So I have gui2py installed on my machine, running the latest version of Phoenix with Python 3.3. Both seem to be working fine. The problem is, when I try to start the Visual Tools editor, with the command that the site said to use:

> Quick Start: Try the sample application in this directory, running:
>   `python sample.pyw` Also, you can start the visual GUI designer with:

```
python -m gui.tools.designer
```

Which tosses me the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'wx.gizmos'
```

When the previous line in the console is:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packges\gui\tools\inspector.py", line 13, in <module>
import wx.gizmos as gizmos
```

Can anybody help me get this running? It is supposed to work with Phoenix and everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications built with gui2py will work on Python 3, but the designer itself will not run on py3k right now because some features are still not ported to wxPhoenix (mainly, property grid and some addons like wx.gizmos are missing or not yet finished in the upcoming version, but wx core developers stated that they will be ported).

Also, if you run your app with prior wxPython versions (for example, wx 2.8), some features also are not available and they will be degraded gracefully ("simulated").

The recommended environment to develop gui2py applications is using Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.9.4.0+.
Then, you can test your app in the other wx and python versions.

You can see the compatibility notes in the main project page: https://code.google.com/p/gui2py/

Comment: thanks. i think i'll stick to py3k for now. At least i know why it isnt working.